# Sporadically datastore entry not updated

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

In my python app, a function called through web API is adding new entries to NDB datastore table sd. It then updates the current entry in table cmpgn to append the reference to the new entry in sd. The code is simple:

```
sd = SendData(data=json_data)
sd.put()

cmpgn.send_data.append(sd.key)
cmpgn.put()
```

However, for about 1 in 50 entries in sd the reference in cmpgn is missing. I didn't find any errors in the logs. What could be the reason for this behavior?

Is it possible, that the function is called again for a new sd entry, before the last function call is finished?

This app is still running in Python 2.7. Could this be a problem? Would the migration to Python 3.x change something about this behavior?

Any other suggestions? Are there tools in Cloud Platform to analyze the behavior?

Comment: Check out datastore transactions for a solution.  You likely have 2 API calls at nearly the same time where one overwrites the other.

Comment: Thanks a lot @gaefan. I think you nailed it. I ended up using threading.Lock() as my ndb model is not using ancestor queries. I think as long as I'm not writing to cmpgn.send_data anywhere else, this should work too.

Comment: Stefan, no that won't work. You need to use transactions.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, two API calls to update entries, [Only the first transaction to commit its changes can succeed; all the others will fail to commit](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/transactions#what_can_be_done_in_a_transaction). The transaction helps hold the lock. So you do not need to apply the lock yourself. However, even the transaction being implemented, the [backoff retry](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/exponential-backoff) still needs to reduce the unexpected DB operation fail. If the I/O very high, you may need to consider the [Transcation task queue](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/transactions#transactional_task_enqueuing) to avoid transaction timeout.